# Como ponerle un pipe a una peticion http

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

Hola estoy haciendo peticiones a mi backend de la siguiente manera, pero quiero agregar la validación de que si el backend devuelve un 401 cierre sesión, entonces el método que hace las peticiones le estoy intentando agregar un pipe que evalué esta condición pero me dice que x.code no existe en el tipo ArrayBuffer alguien me puede decir por que pasa esto?

```
obtener(url: string, params?: any, options?: any): Observable<any> {

        const urlFull = this.getUrl(url, params);
    
        return this.http.get(urlFull, options).pipe(
          map(x => {
            if (x.code == 401) {
              this.closeSessionService.closeSession();
              return;
            }
            return x;
          })
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar de esta forma:

```
obtener(url: string, params?: any, options?: any): Observable<any> {
    const urlFull = this.getUrl(url, params);
    return this.http.get<HttpResponse>(urlFull, options).pipe(
        map(response => {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                this.closeSessionService.closeSession();
                return;
            }
            return response.body;
        })
    );
}
```

En caso de que se quiera hacer la conversión de `ArrayBuffer` a `JSON` primero debes pasar a `JSON` el objeto response con `.json()` ya que es un [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer)  es decir una secuencia de bytes.

```
return this.http.get(urlFull, options).pipe(
      map(x => {
        if (x instanceof HttpResponse) {
            const respuesta = x.json();
            if (respuesta.code == 401) {
              this.closeSessionService.closeSession();
              return;
            }
            return respuesta;
        }
      })
    );
```

y lo otro es que recuerda importar `HttpResponse` en tu servicio que se utiliza para acceder al detalle de la respuesta.

```
import { HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Si en el caso de que recibamos desde el backend `HttpResponse` con cuerpo de `ArrayBuffer` podemos trabajarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
return this.http.get(urlFull, options).pipe(
      map(x => {
        if (x instanceof HttpResponse) {
            x.arrayBuffer().then( (ab) => {
                 if (respuesta.code == 401) {
                      this.closeSessionService.closeSession();
                      return;
                 }
                 return ab;
            });
        }
      })
    );
```

Comment: me aparece esto La propiedad 'json' no existe en el tipo 'ArrayBuffer & HttpResponse<any>'.

Comment: @JuanJose ya veo esto debe ser porque desde el backend recibes un HttpResponse con cuerpo de ArrayBuffer, ya edito mi comentario en un minuto

Comment: Por cierto el proyecto esta usando XMLHttpRequest()
public http = new HttpClient(new HttpXhrBackend({ build: () => new XMLHttpRequest() }))

Comment: ya me sale es La propiedad 'arrayBuffer' no existe en el tipo 'ArrayBuffer & HttpResponse<any>'.ts(2339).

Comment: Ya volví a editar mi comentario prueba con la primera forma que escribí

Comment: La propiedad 'response' no existe en el tipo 'ArrayBuffer'. jajajaja ese array buffer no tiene es nada

Comment: jajaj sí es que va a ser un tema del XMLHttpRequest

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141972/discussion-between-juan-jose-and-edward-romero).